# Case variant exists?

Tags: android, eclipse

I download an APP source code. I upload it first time it debugs well. Then I close and delete the project by accident.

When I uncompress the source code of APP and import source code again, I meet the tip: `case variant exists.`

[image]

Comment: Please paste the link to the source code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had this same issue and the problem was just that I had another project in my workspace with the same name, but different capitalization.  After removing the first project from the workspace it imported fine.

Comment: some projects that might not be visible in eclipse but present in workspace directory so delete them from workspace main directory,then import it works...any way @StapleGun good answer though..

Answer (score 3):

I have not heard of this before - mysterious. I would be that it's related to the Project Name (app name) you entered before you downloaded any source. There is a known issue when special characters like quotes, apostrophes, hyphens, and punctuation are used in project names. I don't know what your project is named but I would start there. If you are using special characters in the name - rename the app in the control panel then re-download the source and see what happens

Comment: This is what happened to me.  I already had a project with the same name.  I was trying to import a new version of my android app with a different version name but the project name was the same.  If you open up a new workspace in eclipse you can verify that it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse project names are NOT case sensitive, that means you can't have two project with same name (but different case); e.g. "myApp" vs. "MyApp"

- check that you don't have similar project in your project list
  (Menu\Window\Show View\Project Explorer or Package Explorer)
- check that you don't have similar project defined in Run
  configuration (Menu\Run\Run Configurations\Adroid Application)

Answer (score 1):

- make sure that you haven't another project with the same name.
- make sure that you don't have any remains from an old project contain
  the same name (SVN files or any hidden file and folder)

Answer (score 1):

Is the file you want to import in workspace folder?If it is so move  it

Answer (score 0):

You just need rename file.zip before extract. Remove special characters like quotes, apostrophes, hyphens, and punctuation are used in project names.